$P_{n}$ is the minimal normal subgroup of $B_{n}$ containing $\sigma_{1}^{2}$ is $ A_{1,2}$
I was reading Braid Groups by Kassel and Turaev, I need to show the following: $P_{n}$ is the minimal normal subgroup of $B_{n}$ containing $\sigma_{1}^{2}$ is $ A_{1,2}$. I know there exists a surjective group homomorphism from $B_{n}$ to $S_{n}$ with kernel $P_{n}$. So I know $P_{n}$ is normal. But how to show that $P_{n}$ is the minimal normal subgroup containing $\sigma_{1}^{2}$. Here $P_{n}$ is the pure braid group on $n$ strands. Thanks in advance.

If you add the relations $\sigma_i^2=1$ for $1 \le i \le n-1$ to the standard presentation of the braid group $B_n$, then you get the Coxeter presentation of $S_n$.
But, since $aba=bab \Rightarrow b^{-1}ab=aba^{-1}$, the generators $\sigma_i$ are all conjugate in $B_n$, so in fact you only need to adjoin the single relation $\sigma_1^2=1$ to get a presentation of $S_n$.
So $P_n$ is the normal closure of $\sigma_1^2$ in $B_n$, and your result follows.
